# Chemmacros scheme translation

Tags: chemmacros, spanish

I'm trying to translate the word "Scheme" in the captions of `chemmacros` schemes. I'm writing in spanish, so I want to change "Scheme 1" to "Esquema 1", for example.

I don't know if I'm not understanding the manual or how the package and module (`lang`) work.

I tried a lot of things so far, but I have this and it gives error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={scheme}}
\DeclareChemTranslation{spanish}{scheme}{esquema}
\DeclareChemTranslation{spanish}{Scheme}{Esquema}

\begin{document}

    \begin{scheme}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

! Package translations Error: Unknown language `scheme'.See the translations package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...reChemTranslation{spanish}{scheme}{esquema}

I'm using this version: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.23) 3 JUN 2019 19:24

Comment: I have added an issue in the `chemmacros` repository: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/24

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One issue is here an error in the manual.

You have to use the following definitions

```
\DeclareChemTranslation{scheme}{spanish}{esquema} % <===================
\DeclareChemTranslation{Scheme}{spanish}{Esquema} % <===================
```

to get no error message. Please see that the order of parameters has changed! First `key`, then `language` and then `translation`. In the manual this is simply wrong (see red arrow with flash), but the second command works as described ...

[image: snippet of manual]

Perhaps because l3kernel has changed it seems that the definitions above do not find their way into the document. Please see the following code

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article} % <====================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={scheme}}
%\chemsetup{language={spanish}}
\DeclareChemTranslation{scheme}{spanish}{esquema} % <===================
\DeclareChemTranslation{Scheme}{spanish}{Esquema} % <===================
%\DeclareChemTranslations{scheme}{spanish=esquema} % <==================
%\DeclareChemTranslations{Scheme}{spanish=Esquema} % <==================


\begin{document}

    \begin{scheme}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

and its result (compiled with MIKTeX version `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)`):

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see the language for `scheme` has not changed!

Now adding

```
\renewcommand{\schemename}{Esquema}
```

after  `\begin{document}` gives you the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

while adding the same line before `\begin{documents}` results in an error because command `\schemename` is only known after document has started ...

I did not investigated now the code (I did not learn using l3kernel until now) what is the reason that the new defined translation for `scheme` in spanish is not printed in the document.

I suggest you make a bug report for the maintainer of that package to get the manual corrected and to get an working translation ...

Answer (score 4):

As @Mensch already mentioned, the manual is wrong and the language should come second. Moreover, the list of translation keys in the manual is also a bit confusing. The list mentions both `scheme` and `scheme-name`, but only `scheme-name` works. This can be traced in the [source code of the scheme module](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/blob/725c7d93626d846313bb71e9ec9ff0a3b271fea2/chemmacros.module.scheme.code.tex) around line 250, where `schema-name` is used for the predefined translation to German - but again somewhat confusingly in a `\ChemCompatibilityTo{5.6}` block, so it might be an old version of the syntax - but at least it works.

An issue on the Github page certainly looks like a good idea, to update the manual and/or the code to make the behavior more intuitive.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={scheme}}
\DeclareChemTranslation{scheme-name}{spanish}{Esquema}

\begin{document}

    \begin{scheme}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A way to change it is simply putting `\renewcommand{\schemename}{Esquema}` after `begin{document}`, but I don't know why I can't change the translation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={scheme}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\schemename}{Esquema}

    \begin{scheme}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{scheme}

\end{document}
```